# How to convert ticks to clock cycles when profiling API calls

Tags: direct3d9

I am profiling Direct3D9 API calls. I have read a lot of documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that describes the process. I have a question though about calculating the elapsed clock cycles. Here is my current method:

```
// measurement vars
LARGE_INTEGER start, stop, freq;

//
// flush command buffer here
//

// 
// issue begin query here
//

// start timer
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

//
//draw
//

//
// issue end query here and wait on results
//

// stop timer
QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);

// calc elapsed ticks
stop.QuadPart -= start.QuadPart;

// get frequency
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

// ticks for easier handling
ULONG ticks = stop.QuadPart;

// calc elapsed clock cycles
cycles = (2.8E9 * ticks) / (double)freq.QuadPart;
```

My question concerns the value 2.8E9 which is supposed to represent the speed of the processor. Is this the correct way of calculating clock cycles? I am profiling single API calls and my results differ from those found on the above link. If I set the processor speed to 1E9 then the numbers are within range...I just wanted to check my method...

Comment: ``ticks`` is already in cycles. You use the frequency to convert cycles to seconds. Read [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks Chuck I agree. But why does the link I provided in the above question suggest that cycle are calculated like this: cycles = processor speed * ticks / frequency? It seems like it has something to do with the frequency with which the timer samples with respect to the processor's speed?

Comment: Frequency is defined as 'cycles per second'. The processor speed determines the frequency in the first place--plus other factors thanks to the complexities of modern power management techniques as discussed in the linked article.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn thanks I guess the method I'm using is correct. It seems to work. I just wanted to make sure

Comment: Except that with that multiplier you are changing from seconds to some other random unit that is ``2.8e9``th of a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of processor cycles is (approximately) the difference.

```
LONGLONG cycles = stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart;
```

The correct way to convert to SECONDS is:

```
double seconds = (double)cycles / (double)freq.QuadPart;
```

`QueryPerformanceCounter` used to be implemented as a wrapper around `RDTSC` but this doesn't work well with modern clock frequency stepping power-management. Therefore, QPC is now usually some other stable clock on the system so it might not necessarily be ' CPU processor cycles'.

If you actually want true 'CPU processor cycles' then you should use `__rdtsc()` intrinsic directly, but remember you don't have a robust way to convert it directly to time--and that on old AMD Athalon 64 machines you have problems of it not being sync'd between cores.

Reserve the use of `ticks`for calls to `GetTickCCount64` (or the deprecated `GetTickCCount`) which returns "ticks in milliseconds".

See [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408.aspx).